# Пронумеровать все записи таблицы (100млн записей) по категориям

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Имеются две таблицы:

```
# около 100 млн записей
CREATE TABLE products (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `categoryId` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `num` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `categoryId` (`categoryId`)
    INDEX `categoryIdNum` (`categoryId, num`)
    ...
);

# около 10 тыс записей
CREATE TABLE categories (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `prodsCnt` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Задача максимально быстро пронумеровать записи в таблице products (поле num) по категориям (id из таблицы categories), при этом не блокируя таблицу на долгое время.

Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нумеровать необходимо не все за один раз (с этим проблем нет).

Нужно нумеровать порциями по 100 записей, например, чтобы не блокировать таблицу, так как другие процессы в этот момент могут вносить изменения в таблицу `products` оператором UPDATE (кроме полей id, categoryId, num).

Первое что приходит на ум - создать первую хранимую процедуру и курсором пройтись по всем записям таблицы `categories`. Из нее для каждой категории делать вызов второй процедуры в которую параметром будет передаваться id категории.

Как правильно организовать работу второй процедуры?, чтобы:

1. обновлять по 100 записей за раз;
2. обеспечить максимальную скорость нумерации и минимальные затраты на поиск записей (таблицы `products`) для обработки.

Идея с LIMIT x, y. Не подходит, так как при каждой итерации будут существенные издержки даже только на поиск записей для обновления.

Возможно предложите совершенно иной подход?

Comment: Делается это через CASE и да - на твой вопрос уже ответили, зря не пользуешься поиском. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql

Comment: Это не ответ на мой вопрос. Предлагаешь за раз обновить 100 млн записей? так не пойдет. "Нужно нумеровать порциями по 100 записей, например, чтобы не блокировать таблицу, так как другие процессы в этот момент могут вносить изменения в таблицу products оператором UPDATE (кроме полей id, categoryId, num)."

Comment: Предлагаю включить мозг и заменить delivered table на temporary table (cat_id, seq), в которой просто сохранять seqence и делать пакетами по 100000 записей. Желательно с остановкой индекса `categoryIdNum` и транзакцией.

Comment: Точную  версию MySQL нам предлагается угадать?

Comment: *Нужно нумеровать порциями по 100 записей, например, чтобы не блокировать таблицу, так как другие процессы в этот момент могут вносить изменения в таблицу products оператором UPDATE (кроме полей id, categoryId, num).* С учётом последнего вообще не вижу проблемы. Копирование двух полей в новую таблицу, нумерация там, копирование обратно. А ещё - если часть полей статическая, а часть частообновляемая,- есть смысл подумать за вертикальный шардинг.

Comment: @Akina, я правильно понимаю? 1) копируем в новую временную таблицу id, categoryId (из таблицы products), добавляем автоинкрементное поле и поле num 2) уже во временной таблице пронумеровываем поле num (все записи за раз) 3) обратно в основную таблицу копируем значения num частями по инкрементному полю временной таблицы. Такой способ выглядит привлекательным. Что-то сразу не додумался про временную таблицу.

Comment: Только вот вопрос про операцию (1). Если копировать INSERT .....  SELECT-ом поля id, categoryId во временную таблицу то в этот момент таблица products будет заблокирована на изменения другими процессами (так как копировать нужно 100млн) или стоит также копировать ее по частям? Надо будет выяснить опытным путем :).

Comment: *Если копировать INSERT ..... SELECT-ом поля id, categoryId во временную таблицу то в этот момент таблица products будет заблокирована на изменения другими процессами* У Вас что, MyISAM? вряд ли... тогда откуда такое странное предположение? Ну то есть блокировки, возможно, и будут, но вряд ли длительные. Да и копировать можно и вправду по частям - например, за один чанк копировать записи для одного значения `categoryId` (благо индекс соответствующий в наличии).

Comment: innoDB. Пробовал операцию 1 провести за раз. И в это же время изменить одну запись в таблице. Последний запрос встал в очередь ожидания.... Короче придется все операции производить по частям.